# Buttons towards the bottom of page not responsive

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a page responsive by using pure CSS. There are 7 buttons at the bottom of the page that should be responsive when the size of the screen is shrunk.

[image: Buttons]

This is what I have been trying:

```css
@media(max-width:360px) {
    #options {
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        outline: none;
        padding-top: 5px;
        overflow: visible;
    }
```

```html
<div id="options">
    <div id="return" title="Return to previous">
        <button id = "btnReturn" class="btn-color"><i id="i-return" class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="save" title="Save">
        <button id = "btnSave" class="btn-color"><i id="i-save" class="fas fa-save fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="list" title="View list">
        <button id = "btnList" class="btn-color"><i id="i-list" class="fas fa-align-justify fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="remove" title="Remove">
        <button id = "btnRemove" class="btn-color"><i id="i-remove" class="fas fa-minus fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="multiply" title="Multiply">
        <button id = "btnMultiply" class="btn-color"><i id="i-multiply" class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="shuffle" title="Shuffle">
        <button id = "btnShuffle" class="btn-color"><i id="i-shuffle" class="fas fa-random fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="setup" title="SetUp">
        <button id = "btnSetup" class="btn-color"><i id="i-setup" class="fas fa-cog fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

But all I get is only upto half of the third button being visible. What should I be adding in the CSS?

Comment: Probably something that changes the size of those buttons themselves, and not just the container …?

Comment: In my opinion the best thing you can do is assign to div id="options" the width of 100%, then to every button id, you have again to set the width to 100% and a float:left; this way you will have buttons displayed in blocks 1 under the other, if you want to achieve something else, like 2 per row, or 3 per row you just have to play with width %

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), a very good tool to make responsive design without having to worry about media queries all the time (of course it's not the answer to everything, but it seems relevant for your problem). You use it only on your media query, and I don't think that's a good solution.

The attribute "flex-wrap" will set the buttons to go under each other depending on the space they have on the screen. Try to resize your screen with the code below and you will see!

If you want to make a line with the buttons, and then directly a column when the screen reaches a certain size, you can add a media query with `flex-direction: column;`.

```css
#options{
   display:flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media(max-width: 360px){
    #options{
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}

#options button{
  width:50px;
  height:30px;
  padding:5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="options">
    <div id="return" title="Return to previous">
        <button id = "btnReturn" class="btn-color"><i id="i-return" class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-left fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="save" title="Save">
        <button id = "btnSave" class="btn-color"><i id="i-save" class="fas fa-save fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="list" title="View list">
        <button id = "btnList" class="btn-color"><i id="i-list" class="fas fa-align-justify fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="remove" title="Remove">
        <button id = "btnRemove" class="btn-color"><i id="i-remove" class="fas fa-minus fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="multiply" title="Multiply">
        <button id = "btnMultiply" class="btn-color"><i id="i-multiply" class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="shuffle" title="Shuffle">
        <button id = "btnShuffle" class="btn-color"><i id="i-shuffle" class="fas fa-random fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div id="setup" title="SetUp">
        <button id = "btnSetup" class="btn-color"><i id="i-setup" class="fas fa-cog fa-2x"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```